# JUnit testcases is throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit

I am trying to executing basic testcase, which I have completed doing setup and I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.getLauncherDiscoveryListener(LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:241)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.build(LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
```

Find below my `ConfigServer` class:

```
package org.siaa.devops;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final String PREFERRED_AUTENTICATION_MODE = "publickey";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Hack in JSCH to avoid interactive session
        // Override PreferredAuthentications in JSCH
        Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications", PREFERRED_AUTENTICATION_MODE);
        JSch.setConfig(config);

        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ConfigServer.class);
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
group 'org.siaa.develop'

buildscript {
    ext {
        //springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
        //springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

//version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

//springBoot {
  //executable = true
//}

bootJar {
    launchScript()
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Hoxton.SR3'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://artifactory.siaa.org/artifactory/siaa-mp-develop'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:2.2.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.2.6.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:2.2.1.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    
    //Kafka and spring cloud config monitor
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka:2.0.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-monitor:2.2.1.RELEASE')
    
    //Prometheus
    compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus')
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0")

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Added testcase is `ConfigServerTest`

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ConfigServerTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I have done research and same code seems to working fine in other machine but causing issue in my local.
Unable to fix it. Please help me out with it.

Gradle version I am using is: Gradle-6.5.1
Java (JRE)version :1.8.0_40

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By doing right click in class and then by running as JUnit test